# spring data with elasticsearch fails on findTopByOrderBy

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I'm using spring data with elastic search.
My Repository class has a method to get the latest insert in the index.

```
Product findTop1ByOrderByIdDesc();
```

By this fails with the following exception.

> java.lang.NullPointerException: null  at
>   org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchTemplate.queryForPage(ElasticsearchTemplate.java:307)
>   ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:na]     at
>   org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchTemplate.queryForObject(ElasticsearchTemplate.java:251)
>   ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:na]     at
>   org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.query.ElasticsearchPartQuery.execute(ElasticsearchPartQuery.java:78)
>   ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:na]     at
>   org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:482)
>   ~[spring-data-commons-1.12.1.RELEASE.jar:na]  at
>   org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:460)
>   ~[spring-data-commons-1.12.1.RELEASE.jar:na]  at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
>   ~[spring-aop-4.3.0.RC2.jar:4.3.0.RC2]     at
>   org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:61)
>   ~[spring-data-commons-1.12.1.RELEASE.jar:na]  at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
>   ~[spring-aop-4.3.0.RC2.jar:4.3.0.RC2]     at
>   org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
>   ~[spring-aop-4.3.0.RC2.jar:4.3.0.RC2]     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
>   ~[spring-aop-4.3.0.RC2.jar:4.3.0.RC2]     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
>   ~[spring-aop-4.3.0.RC2.jar:4.3.0.RC2]     at
>   com.sun.proxy.$Proxy92.findTop1ByOrderByIdDesc(Unknown Source)
>   ~[na:na]

I've debugged the spring-data code and found that 'query' is null for the method
`ElasticsearchTemplate.queryForPage`

Can someone help me in resolving this?

Comment: Which elasticsearch version you are using?

Comment: Elasticsearch 2.2.2

Comment: Have you checked the spring data elasticsearch support for the 2.2.2 version of elasticsearch?

Answer (score 0):

try Product findTopByOrderByIdDesc();

Comment: It didn't work either. It failed with the same error